Trying to figure out how to implement ImGWO
I used Google Gemini to populate this piece of code, but I have no idea how to use it.
I was working on a project for anomaly detection and training my model. I did a little research and found that the Improved Grey wolf algorithm performs well in detecting anomalies.
It would be a great help if someone could help me figure out this.
# prompt: implement improved Grey wolf optimizer Algorithm for the above models with x_train_scaled and x_test_scaled

import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Assuming x_train_scaled and x_test_scaled are defined from previous code

def improved_grey_wolf_optimizer(objective_function, lb, ub, dim, SearchAgents_no=50, Max_iter=1000):
    # Initialize alpha, beta, and delta_pos
    Alpha_pos = np.zeros(dim)
    Alpha_score = float('inf')

    Beta_pos = np.zeros(dim)
    Beta_score = float('inf')

    Delta_pos = np.zeros(dim)
    Delta_score = float('inf')

    # Initialize the positions of search agents
    Positions = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (SearchAgents_no, dim)) * (ub - lb) + lb
    Convergence_curve = np.zeros(Max_iter)

    # Main loop
    for l in range(0, Max_iter):
        for i in range(0, SearchAgents_no):
            # Return back the search agents that go beyond the boundaries of the search space
            for j in range(dim):
              Positions[i, j] = np.clip(Positions[i, j], lb[j], ub[j])

            # Calculate objective function for each search agent
            fitness = objective_function(Positions[i, :])

            # Update Alpha, Beta, and Delta
            if fitness < Alpha_score:
                Alpha_score = fitness
                Alpha_pos = Positions[i, :].copy()

            if fitness > Alpha_score and fitness < Beta_score:
                Beta_score = fitness
                Beta_pos = Positions[i, :].copy()

            if fitness > Alpha_score and fitness > Beta_score and fitness < Delta_score:
                Delta_score = fitness
                Delta_pos = Positions[i, :].copy()

        a = 2 - l * ((2) / Max_iter)  # a decreases linearly from 2 to 0

        # Update the Position of search agents including omegas
        for i in range(0, SearchAgents_no):
            for j in range(0, dim):
                r1 = np.random.rand()
                r2 = np.random.rand()
                A1 = 2 * a * r1 - a
                C1 = 2 * r2

                D_alpha = abs(C1 * Alpha_pos[j] - Positions[i, j])
                X1 = Alpha_pos[j] - A1 * D_alpha

                r1 = np.random.rand()
                r2 = np.random.rand()
                A2 = 2 * a * r1 - a
                C2 = 2 * r2

                D_beta = abs(C2 * Beta_pos[j] - Positions[i, j])
                X2 = Beta_pos[j] - A2 * D_beta

                r1 = np.random.rand()
                r2 = np.random.rand()
                A3 = 2 * a * r1 - a
                C3 = 2 * r2

                D_delta = abs(C3 * Delta_pos[j] - Positions[i, j])
                X3 = Delta_pos[j] - A3 * D_delta

                Positions[i, j] = (X1 + X2 + X3) / 3

        Convergence_curve[l] = Alpha_score

    return Alpha_pos, Convergence_curve


# Example usage (replace with your actual objective function and bounds)
def objective_function(solution):
  # This is where you integrate your model with GWO, predict using solution (weights)
  # Then calculate the error from y_test for example.
  # Replace this with your actual model evaluation function
  # The following are just random values to run the example.
  y_pred = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=len(x_test_scaled))
  return 1 - accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)

lb = np.array([-1]*x_train_scaled.shape[1])  # Replace with lower bounds
ub = np.array([1]*x_train_scaled.shape[1])   # Replace with upper bounds
dim = x_train_scaled.shape[1]

gwo_y_pred, convergence_curve = improved_grey_wolf_optimizer(objective_function, lb, ub, dim)
gwo_y_pred

# print("Improved Grey Wolf Optimiser Report:")
# print(classification_report(y_test, gwo_y_pred))
print("Improved Grey Wolf Optimiser Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_test, gwo_y_pred))

this was implemented using SVM,
hope this might help if you are trying to figure out what I was doing before implementing this.
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import warnings
from sklearn.exceptions import DataConversionWarning

# Suppress DataConversionWarning
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=DataConversionWarning)

# Support Vector Machine Classifier with default parameters
svm_model = SVC(random_state=42)

# Fit the model on the training data
svm_model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train.to_numpy().ravel())

# Make predictions on the test set
svm_y_pred = svm_model.predict(x_test_scaled)

# Performance metrics for SVM
print("SVM Classification Report:")
print(classification_report(y_test, svm_y_pred))
print("SVM Accuracy:", accuracy_score(y_test, svm_y_pred))

